# Multiple scala directories in sbt project with intelliJ-IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

How to avoid the creation of multiple scala directories in sbt project automatically ?

```
___ main
 |_ java
 |_ ressources
 |_ scala
 |_ scala-2.11
___ test
 |_ java
 |_ ressources
 |_ scala
 |_ scala-2.11
```

my sbt file :

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you create your project using IntelliJ IDEA? I've seen this a lot and it's actually misleading.

You can safely delete the directories you're not going to use. `src/main/scala` is where source files are expected. `src/main/resources` is for files you want to include in your jar (or be accessible anyway at runtime), and `src/main/java` is for Java sources (obviously `test` counterparts apply for every directory).

Source: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html (which doesn't mention at all scala-2.11)

Comment: yes I am using intelliJ IDEA. yep it is clear, is there a solution to avoid creating unwanted directory ?

Comment: Untick the "Create empty directory roots" option - but then you'll have to create `src/main/scala` etc by hand.

Comment: in this case deleting the scala-2.11 directory will be the easiest one

Comment: I don't use `java` so usually I don't create empty root. Anyway your mileage may vary - feel free to use the best option that suits you! Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: thanks for your help! but actually I am looking for auto-solution

Comment: Not a problem :) However please consider editing your question as it is not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @SaKou This an issue with intellij. I don't think you can come up with an automated solution. In any case, I usually create a project without intellij (manually or with an activator template), and open it in intellij.